# document.referrer help Javascript

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if someone could help me, I have the following javascript code on my website:

```
<body onload="if (document.referrer == '') self.location='https://www.thisisanexampleofmysiteurl.com';">
```

But I was wondering if there was a way to modify it so it contained an exception to the rule. For example, if a user typed in the url directly they would be sent to https://www.thisisanexampleofmysiteurl.com but if they were referred from a URL shortener (say fakeexample.com) then the actual web page would load rather than https://www.thisisanexampleofmysiteurl.com

Hopefully this makes sense and someone can help.

Thanks,

S

Comment: Redirects don't set `document.referrer`, so there's no way to tell that you came to the page through a redirect from a shortener.

Answer (score 1):

you can add to that piece of code an `else if` that detects through a RegExp if the referrer is a URL shortener:

```
var regExp = /http:\/\/(bit.ly|goo.gl)/g;
var dr = document.referrer;
if (dr == '') {

    self.location='https://www.thisisanexampleofmysiteurl.com';

} else if (dr.match(regExp)) {

    self.location='http://www.whateverURLyouWantToLoadInstead.com';

}
```

I think it might be a good idea to include this code in a `$(document).ready(function(){...});` as it would be more clear.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, just a quick addition. If the ULR shortener was https://anon.to would it just be a case of changing bit.ly | goo.gl to https://anon.to?

Comment: exactly, it would be something like `/http:\/\/anon.to/g`

Comment: I thought that's what you wanted to do.

Comment: Just tried it and it redirected me to http://www.whateverURLyouWantToLoadInstead.com rather than the page on the site the URL shortener should go to. I am assuming that is because I just used anon.to rather than anon.to/xxxx (hoping it would let anything from anon.to through). - Sorry wasn't clear with this, I meant the whateverurlyouwanttoloadinstead would be dynamically chosen so is not fixed so basically loads whatever the anon.to link is

Comment: So, basically, for clarification purposes this is what I would (ideally) want: X person has anon.to/xxxx link so this takes them to Y and another person has anon.to/yyyy link so this takes them to x, while keeping var dr = document.referrer;
if (dr == '') {

    self.location='https://www.thisisanexampleofmysiteurl.com'; the same.